# Update class object list

Tags: python, oop, singleton

I have a list of objects at the class level, and a class method `fight` which operates with the objects from that list:

```
from Heroes import Hero
from Creatures import Creature
from random import randint

class Battle():
    """template to simulate the battle"""


    obj_list = []

    def __init__(self,obj1_name,obj2_name):

        #create  hero
        self.obj1 = Hero(obj1_name, health = randint(70,100), strength = randint(70,80), defence = randint(45,55), speed = randint(40,50), luck = randint(10,30))
        Battle.obj_list.append(self.obj1)



        #create  creature
        self.obj2 = Creature(obj2_name, health = randint(70,100), strength = randint(70,80), defence = randint(45,55), speed = randint(40,50), luck = randint(10,30))
        Battle.obj_list.append(self.obj2)

    @classmethod
    def fight(cls):
        """simulate fight"""

        # first attack is landed by the obj with highest speed
        if cls.obj_list[0].speed > cls.obj_list[1].speed:

           cls.obj_list[1].health =  cls.obj_list[0].attack() - cls.obj_list[1].defence

        # same speed first attack landed by the obj with highest luck
        elif cls.obj_list[0].speed == cls.obj_list[1].speed:

            if cls.obj_list[0].luck >= cls.obj_list[1].luck:
                cls.obj_list[1].health =  cls.obj_list[0].attack() - cls.obj_list[1].defence
            else:
                cls.obj_list[0].health =  cls.obj_list[1].attack() - cls.obj_list[0].defence

        #self.obj1.speed < self.obj2.speed
        else:
                cls.obj_list[0].health =  cls.obj_list[1].attack() - cls.obj_list[0].defence

        return cls.obj_list

if __name__ == "__main__":

    first_round =  Battle("Icarus","Beast")


    for i in Battle.obj_list:
            print(i.name,i.health)

    Battle.fight()


    for i in Battle.obj_list:
            print(i.name,i.health)

    Battle.fight()

    for i in Battle.obj_list:
            print(i.name,i.health)
```

Output:

```
Icarus 90
Beast 74
Icarus 30
Beast 74
Icarus 30
Beast 74
```

The first call of the `fight` method updates correctly the `health` attribute of the objects from `obj_list` but then no matter how many times I call the method,  `health` attribute it's not updated anymore. What am I missing, should I use another approach to share the state for objects ?

Comment: First: global variables, even if they have a `.` in their names, are bad (although games in particular often ignore this for somewhat-valid performance reasons that aren’t relevant for Python).  Second: you never *read* `health` and never write anything else, so why would anything be different the second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a class attribute as storage for hero and creature is unneccessary and makes the code unreadable.

With your approach, after three fights Battle.obj_list will look like that:

[Hero(first fight), Creature(first fight), Hero(second fight), Creature(second fight), Hero(third fight), Creature(third fight)].

In your code you always access [0] and [1].

Next thing is that you create hero and creature in a battle.
You can imagine like in the 'reality': The hero and the creature exist before the battle and when the battle starts (Battle-instance created) the go into the battle.

```py
class Battle():
    """template to simulate the battle"""
    def __init__(self, hero, creature):

        #create  hero
        self.hero = hero

        #create  creature
        self.creature = creature

    def fight(self):
        """simulate fight"""

        # first attack is landed by the obj with highest speed
        if self.hero.speed > self.creature.speed:
           self.creature.health =  self.hero.attack() - self.creature.defence

        # same speed first attack landed by the obj with highest luck
        elif self.hero.speed == self.creature.speed:
            if self.hero.luck >= self.creature.luck:
                self.creature.health =  self.hero.attack() - self.creature.defence
            else:
                self.hero.health =  self.creature.attack() - self.hero.defence

        #self.obj1.speed < self.obj2.speed
        else:
            self.hero.health =  self.creature.attack() - self.hero.defence
        return [self.hero, self.creature]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hero = Hero(
        obj1_name, health = randint(70,100),
        strength = randint(70,80),
        defence = randint(45,55),
        speed = randint(40,50),
        luck = randint(10,30)
        )

    creature = Creature(
        obj2_name,
        health = randint(70,100),
        strength = randint(70,80),
        defence = randint(45,55),
        speed = randint(40,50),
        luck = randint(10,30)
        )

    first_round =  Battle(hero, creature)
```

It would be good if you'd post Creature and Hero class